# Did Bayaz have plans for Sand dan Glokta before meeting him?

Tags: joe-abercrombie, the-first-law

My question is did Bayaz plan to make Sand dan Glokta

> Arch Lector

before his raids on Mercers or it was after that?

Because based on this, It looks like Bayaz had planned to use Sand dan Glokta.

> “There will need to be some witnesses present, of course, to make sure that I don't try any sleight of hand. How about..." Bayaz' cool green eyes swept down the table. "Inquisitor Glokta, and... your new fencing champion, Captain Luthar?”
>
> <sub><sup>*The Blade Itself, The Ideal Audience*</sup></sub>

I ask this because Bayaz had planned on using Logen, Ferro and Jezal some time before the events of The Blade Itself?

Answer (score 4):

I think Bayaz had not planned on selecting Sand dan Glotka. There are some clues.

> “Glokta stuck out his bottom lip. “But then Feekt died, and you were left naked.”
>
> “Naked as a babe, at my age.” Bayaz gave a long sigh. “And in poor weather too, with Khalul making ready for war. I should have arranged a suitable successor more quickly, but my thoughts were elsewhere, deep in my books. The older you get, the more swiftly the years pass. It’s easy to forget how quickly people die.”
>
> <sup><sub>*Last Argument of Kings, Answers*</sub></sup>

Feekt died while Sand dan Glotka was dealing with Salem Rews.

> Sult's frown grew still deeper. "And now Feekt is dead.”
>
> Glokta looked up. Now that is news. "The Lord Chancellor?”
>
> “It will become public knowledge tomorrow morning. He died suddenly a few nights ago, while you were busy with your friend Rews.”
>
> <sup><sub>*The Blade Itself, The Morning Ritual*</sub></sup>

So Bayaz had not decided on a successor for Lord Chancellor Feekt till at least, Sand dan Glotka started investigating the Mercers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, Bayaz is a known liar and Bayaz knew that the Arch lector would have to go for the sake of order. I would imagine the Rews investigation is what put Glokta on his radar, considering the questions about a certain bank.

If anything Bayaz knew there had to be some replacement and that Glokta was the perfect candidate once he was made Inquisitor Exempt and was debuted by Sult as a prolific Inquisitor before the open counsel.

It's kind of like Jezal, Bayaz found a few options and Glokta made himself rise to the top. I would venture as far as to say that if Glokta failed Harlen Morrow would have taken the job as High Justice and lead the closed counsel.